# Microsoft SQL Server , view transformation

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, cross-join, database-view

Is it possible to transform the following view :

[image]

to this structure ?

[image]

I've tried with cross join but I have no idea how to make a condition based on column name.

Comment: Please explain the logic you are after

Comment: Could you please explain the logic of this transformation? How was 98% converted into 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `APPLY` instead of `JOIN` to be able to access outer columns

```
SELECT t.Date, v.[1], v.[2], v.number
FROM Table t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    (t.[1], CAST(NULL AS int), 1),
    (NULL, t.[2], 2)
) v ([1], [2], number)
```